# How can I use RLIKE to effectively combine LIKE and IN, *and* escape regex characters where needed?

Tags: php, sql, regex, get

I need to figure out how to query my database for *Serial A* or *Serial B* or *Serial C*, however there are a variety of constraints making this difficult to navigate.

The previous solution used `LIKE` (e.g. `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Serial LIKE`) - this worked well for searching for all serials (`%`) or a specific serial (`Serial A`). However, I quickly found that `IN` and `LIKE` cannot be combined in MySql, and that the wildcards used by `LIKE` are not flexible enough to find *Serial A* or *Serial B* or *Serial C*.

*(Note: The actual serials have a great deal of variation and no consistent convention - I'm aware that serials as simple as these basic examples could be found using the `%` wildcard)*

My immediate thought was to use `RLIKE` instead - however some of the serials are named things such as `B + 3`, and cannot be found without escaping. Here, I thought to use a method to escape the characters, such as `preg_quote()` - however therein lies more problems with the structure of the system...

---

**Select Constraints Module**

A combobox is populated by querying the database (e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT Serial FROM Table`) from which the users can select a serial, and then submit the form. The selected serial is passed as a `GET` value to the next page.

**View Results Module**

The contents of a `$serial` variable are passed as a parameter to a SQL query to generate results on the page. `$serial` is either populated by the page the View Results Module is part of, or by the `GET` value passed to the page (if the value hasn't been populated by the page before the module is `include`d and there is no `GET` value, an error will be thrown).

---

Its this structure that's confusing me a little. It seems like it would be pretty straightforward to use `RLIKE` and `preg_quote()` to search for a serial if this was passed by the user. `preg_quote()` can be used on `$serial` before it is passed as a parameter and the updated (`WHERE Serial RLIKE`) query should work as expected. However, I still can't figure out how to search for *more than one* serial.

If I specify `$serial` as `(Serial A | Serial B | Serial C)` then `preg_quote()` will escape the regex characters and not find them. But if I don't use `preg_quote()`, serials such as `B + 3` will not be found because regex characters are left unescaped.

---

I'd very much appreciate any feedback on improving this question - I've tried to explain it as clearly as possible but the complexity of the context and constraints make it difficult. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the substrings, not the final regexp.

```
"(" . preg_quote(serialA) . "|" . preg_quote(serialB) . "|" . preg_quote(serialC) . ")"
```

Comment: Hmmm... I was about to say that I can't do that because the module doesn't `know` if it got the `$serial` from a `GET` variable or from the page its in - but I can just assign `$serial` with `preg_quote($_GET[Serial])` - so it can effectively 'know'. D'oh. Thanks!